# Is there a way to use Java 8 functional interfaces on Android API below 24?

Tags: java, android, lambda, functional-interface, retrolambda

I can use retrolambda to enable lambdas with Android API level <24.
So this works

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(view -> Timber.d("Lambdas work!"));
```

This also works

```
Runnable runLater = () -> Timber.d("Lambdas work!");
runLater.run();
```

But this one does not

```
Consumer<Integer> runLaterWithInt = (Integer i) -> Timber.d("i = " + i);
runLaterWithInt.accept(3);
```

The last one works on Android API Level 24, but on other devices this code causes a crash

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.retrolambdatry.MainActivity$$Lambda$1
```

Instead of using retrolambda I tried to enable Java 8. First two code examples still work, although butterknife stopped working. https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html#configuration here `ava.util.function` is said to be supported, but I still get a crash when running the third one, this time it is a little different

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.retrolambdatry.MainActivity$-void_onCreate_android_os_Bundle_savedInstanceState_LambdaImpl1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Java 8 work on Android api 23 and above?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35934528/does-java-8-work-on-android-api-23-and-above)

Comment: The question is poorly titled; lambdas are actually being backported to older Android versions, so you don't need Retrolambda. Just install the new Android Studio and build tools.

Comment: Perhaps it is poorly titled.  As i understand I don't need retorlambda if I have Android N SDK and I enable Jack compile options. Lambdas work either way. But functional interfaces from 'java.util.function' still don't.

Comment: The problem is that the Jack compiler prevents the use of the Data Binding Library (see [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210615)). That's why many people might not be willing to use Jack at the moment, but Retrolambda as an alternative to get lambda expressions (until the issues will be fixed in a future Android Studio version).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Not sure if you still need an answer to this question, but others (like myself) might.

As version 3.0, Android Studio [natively supports lambda functions](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html) and many other Java 8 functions on all API levels, but some (like Functional Interfaces and `java.util.function`) are still restricted to APIs 24+.

Until that support is expanded, [android-retrostreams](https://github.com/retrostreams/android-retrostreams) provides backport support for most of it. This project is an 'upgraded port' of the [streamsupport library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/), which you can also use and has many of the functionalities in android-retrostreams. The streamsupport library supports down to Java 6/7, so you can use it even if you don't have AS 3.0+ or aren't targeting Java 8, but you're probably better off using android-retrostreams in most cases, if you can. You can go through the project's javadocs to see exactly what's offered, but highlights that I've used are `java.util.function` and `java.util.Comparator`.

Note that `java` in the package names is replaced with `java9`, and some of the class and/or method names may have been changed slightly. For example:

`java.util.function` becomes `java9.util.function`,

while

`java.util.Comparator` becomes `java9.util.Comparators` (and with slightly different method names and call patterns - but the same functionality).

Comment: Correction: [android-retrostreams](https://github.com/retrostreams/android-retrostreams) *doesn't* work on Java 7 if you have a Java 7 Oracle / OpenJDK VM in mind. It *does*  work on Android devices down to API level 15 or 14 regardless of the Java version that was then current, *provided* you use Android Studio 3.x and its Java 8 capabilities to develop an app for such devices (it wouldn't work with Android Studio 2.3.x). If you need a Stream API backport that indeed *works* on a real Java 6 / 7 VM (Sun etc.) you'll have to use [streamsupport](https://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/).

Comment: Ah, my bad. The `android-retrostreams` readme made it sound like they only dropped support for Java 6, and that it would work for Android Studio even if you weren't explicitly targeting Java 8. I never actually tried it, though. I'll edit for clarification, just in case.

Comment: How does it matter which Java version you are targeting in Android Studio 3.x? In the end, it's the *minSDKVersion* that decides whether your app runs on, let's say Marshmallow. So, just to avoid possible confusion: let *minSDKVersion = 23* (Marshmallow), then "target" Java 8 in Android Studio 3.x and use `android-retrostreams` and you'll be fine. What i'm saying is, that the `android-retrostreams` **jar** file can't be run on a Java 7 Standard Edition VM (JRE from Oracle, IBM ...)

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you have to target Java 8 anyway if you want use Java 8 language features like lambdas, method references or interface default methods. That's totally dis-connected from the *minSDKVersion* as long as you **do not** use API calls (like something from java.util.function) that are specific to Java 8. `android-retrostreams` brings in *replacements* for these Java 8 APIs that will even work on *Ice Cream Sandwich* (which definitely was Java 6).

Comment: what's the different with `retro-lambda`? @VerumCH

EDITED: 

after reading it carefully, retrolambda is [lacks support for 3rd-party libs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html#migrate_from_retrolambda). we should really use the `android-retrostreams`

Answer (score 12):

Android support library(AndroidX) now has `Consumer` and `Supplier`:

- [androidx.core.util.Consumer](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/util/Consumer) (appears in `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2`)
- [androidx.core.util.Supplier](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/util/Supplier) (appears in `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01`)

sadly [only these two interfaces gets added](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/util/package-summary) as of writing.

Now we have Kotlin, it doesn't require you to specify the functional interface explicitly:

```
    fun test() {
        val text = withPrintStream {
            it.println("Header bla bla ")
            it.printf("%s, %s, %s,", "a", "b", "c").println()
        }
    }

    // Equivalent to the following code in Java:
    //     Consumer<PrintStream> action;
    //     action.accept(ps);
    fun withPrintStream(action: (PrintStream) -> Unit): String {
        val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        val ps = PrintStream(byteArrayOutputStream)
        action(ps)
        ps.flush()
        return byteArrayOutputStream.toString()
    }
```

Comment: this is an old question. Kotlin solves this, but at the time of asking Kotlin wasn't really an option.

Comment: This answer helped me as I'm stuck with Java for now. Cheers!

Comment: This is still helpful as it also works in API Level < 24 when using Java code.

Comment: really helpful !!! Along with this library-desugaring needed to add 
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring

Answer (score 3):

Android Gradle plugin (AGP) 4.0+ add backported support for java8 packages (such as java.util.function, which added to Android API 24) on low API version:

see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring

Adding lines from code below to APP module allows me to use openAPI-generator 5.1.0 produced java jersey API-SDK module with Android API < 24 (I use jersey for better polymorphism support)

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    // Required when setting minSdkVersion to 20 or lower
    multiDexEnabled true
  }

  compileOptions {
    // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
    coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}

dependencies {
  coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For alternative, [Lightweight-Stream-API](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API) also provides backport support. Like [android-retrostreams](https://github.com/retrostreams/android-retrostreams) metioned above, you have to replace some package names by using:
`com.annimon.stream.function` instead of `java.util.function`
`com.annimon.stream.ComparatorCompat` instead of `java.util.Comparator`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
import androidx.core.util.Consumer;
```

instead of

```
import java.util.function.Consumer; (requires min API 24)
```

Sample implementation

```
public static void sampleMethod(Consumer<Boolean> isClicked) {
    isClicked.accept(true);
}
```

usage of sample implementation

```
Utils.sampleMethod(new Consumer<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Boolean isClicked) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
dependencies {
        compile 'com.github.ipcjs:java-support:0.0.3'
}
```

code: [ipcjs/java-support](https://github.com/ipcjs/java-support)

Comment: what is this and why does it help?

Comment: @jpcjs yeah I've already looked at that, but that isn't much of documentation. My question remains ^^ what is this? just a complete copy of android? and why does that work?

Comment: @lucidbrot Reference:[Use Java 8 Language Features | Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html)、[Lambda Expressions (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Classes and Objects)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)