# Unable to use forEach and lambda in android min sdk version less than 24

Tags: android, lambda, foreach, java-8

I am using jack compiler in my android project. My min sdk is set to 18. I am unable to use forEach and lambda in my code. It asks me to change my min sdk to 24 or higher. I was hoping that with the integration of JACK compiler I would be able to use this forEach with lambda easily. Is there any work around for this other than bumping up the min sdk?

Comment: Jack gives you lambdas and method references but it can't magically extend the available API. `forEach` is a default method added to `java.lang.Iterable` in Java 8 (Android API level 24). You'd have to use a backport library to be able use some of the new APIs with min sdk < 24.

Comment: If you want something `Stream` like on Android 6.x and below you should have a look at the [streamsupport](https://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/) or [LWS](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API) libraries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515035/is-it-possible-to-use-the-java-8-stream-api-on-android-api-24

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use the Java 8 Stream API on Android API < 24?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515035/is-it-possible-to-use-the-java-8-stream-api-on-android-api-24)