# Does Android desugar Java 8 Iterable.forEach() with minSdkVersion<24?

Tags: android, foreach, java-8

I was very excited hearing about Google's [desugar project](https://youtu.be/gGOOkk2y_Ss?t=253) since I have to support `minSdkVersion 17`.

I went ahead and tried a simple Java 8 example:

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("element1","element2","element3");
myList.forEach(element -> System.out.println(element));
```

However, Android Studio says `Call requires API level 24 (current min is 17): java.lang.Iterable#forEach`

Google [issued a table about what features are supported](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#supported_features). Does their documentation mention whether or not `Iterable.forEach()` is supported in any minSdkVersion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`forEach` uses a type from `java.util.function` which is only supported (with desugaring) [on API level 24 or higher](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#supported_features).

There are libraries that add support for streams. [See this answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39515397/2232127).

Comment: Ah ok, [java.util.stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) is part of their [list](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#supported_features) where it says "requires minSdkVersion >=24".

Answer (score 0):

`Iterable#forEach` is supported via desugaring. There's a reference table you can search Java 8+ APIs supported by desugaring: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table.

Just follow the documentation on [Java 8+ API desugaring support](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) to set it up.

Comment: That seems to be added in Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.0+ according to https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#supported_features. However, I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: @OneWorld yes! it's AGP 4.0+ added more desugaring. thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Yes, according to Google, it appears to be supported with Gradle 4+ but Android Studio is still flagging that it requires at least API 24.

Comment: @ichalos I'm finding the same. I've raised a bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/232808529