# What's the Java equivalent of this Kotlin declaration?

Tags: java, kotlin

What's the Java equivalent of this Kotlin declaration?

```kotlin
var doOnAppCouldNotBeFrozen: ((Context) -> Unit)? = null
```

I think this is a "function type" but I'm not sure. Is it a method or a variable? I know that Unit means void so then is it a method that returns void?

The only way I can understand what it means is if I can see how it's written in Java (without the question mark after Unit).

Comment: It's the definition of a variable, holding a lambda of type `(Context) -> Unit` (a function that takes in a `Context` and returns a `Unit`), and it is nullable.

Comment: Well then maybe if your experience is all your questions getting downvoted, you should read [ask]? I think the comment from @Turing85 explains it perfectly.

Comment: There is no 1:1 relation since Java has no concept of non-nullableness. If we ignore this, the equivalent would be `Function<Context, Void> doOnAppCouldNotBeFrozen = null;` or `Consumer<Function> doOnAppCouldNotBeFrozen = null;`

Comment: @Turing85 I'm confused now. Is it a variable or a function? I've never seen that kind of statement in java before

Comment: It is a variable. If you have never seen the concept, I recommend reading a tutorial on lambdas, e.g. [this one by oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), as well as the [documentation of the `java.util.function`-package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/package-summary.html).

Comment: I didn't make my suggestion to prevent you from getting downvoted. I made the suggestion because if this question is to be useful for future readers than they must be able to find it and your original title is not really searchable.

Comment: @FarouFaroud *"Is it a variable or a function?"* It's kind of a variable *to* a function.

Comment: @Andreas Functions are not first-class citizens in Java. It is actually a variable holding a reference to a concrete interface-implementation. This may or may not be a lambda expression or a method reference, both of which, as far as I know, get compiled-down to an anonymous interface implementations.

Comment: @Turing85 "Kind of" means "not really, but abstractly it behaves very close to that". --- And no, lambdas and method references never become anonymous classes. A lambda becomes a hidden (synthetic) method and is then a method reference to that hidden method.

Comment: @Turing85 in Android studio trying to use the `accept` or `apply` methods after defining those interfaces always says they require min API 24

Comment: @FarouFaroud Lambdas and the `java.util.function`-package were introduced in Java 8.

Comment: @Turing85 So what to do if I target lower APIs?

Comment: @FarouFaroud Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: @Turing85 To be pedantic, a lambda isn’t a type of object. It is one of many possible syntaxes used to define a function. The variable here is not of a lambda type. You could assign any function with matching type, not just ones defined by lambdas.

Comment: @Tenfour04 For Kotlin, I take you word for it :) (I am not as firm in Kotlin's spec as I am in Java's). For Java, the last information I had was that lambdas are "just" syntactic sugar for anonymous interface implementations.

Answer (score 2):

The java equivalent of the kotlin code is:

```java
Consumer<Context> doOnAppCouldNotBeFrozen = null;
```

If you want to learn more about the [Consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html), I can recommend the documentation.

**EDIT**: Using the java stream below api 24 requires [desugaring to be enabled](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring):

> If you're building your app using Android Gradle plugin 4.0.0 or higher, the plugin extends support for using a number of Java 8 language APIs without requiring a minimum API level for your app.

Comment: Ok so I have to use `doOnAppCouldNotBeFrozen.accept(context)` to use it later? Android Studio says the accept() method requires API 24

Comment: Yes that is correct. And I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515035/is-it-possible-to-use-the-java-8-stream-api-on-android-api-24). So it is not possible to use the java stream below api 24.

Answer (score -2):

To get `Java` equivalent of every `Kotlin` code

Select `Tools > Kotlin > Show Kotlin Bytecode`

[image: Screenshot 2021-04-03 at 15 01 49]

Then click `DECOMPILE`

[image: Screenshot 2021-04-03 at 15 08 03]

This is Java equivalent in `Android Studio`

```java
   @Nullable
   private static Function1 doOnAppCouldNotBeFrozen;

   @Nullable
   public static final Function1 getDoOnAppCouldNotBeFrozen() {
      return doOnAppCouldNotBeFrozen;
   }

   public static final void setDoOnAppCouldNotBeFrozen(@Nullable Function1 var0) {
      doOnAppCouldNotBeFrozen = var0;
   }
```

Comment: You may want to mention which IDE you are using.

Comment: I am using Android Studio

Comment: Maybe you want to [edit] your answer and include this information?

Comment: While we are on the topic: You may want to include the definition of `Function1` aswell.

Comment: The `Function1` was generated by the IDE

Comment: I doubt that. If it appears in the bytecode, it should have been generated by the compiler. Anyway, the definition of `Function1` is where the actual magic happens.

Comment: Actually the ``Function1`` is the `Type`.

Comment: @Turing85 `Function1` is likely a (static) nested interface generated by Kotlin. Since it is a different type, the UI likely didn't show it, it only showed the bytecode of the main type in the source file. Limit of the IDE.

Comment: @KakyireLastBorn yes, but the type needs an implementation, that is where the "mapping" from the kotlin-syntax to the JVM-code (an, in last instance, the Java-code) happens.

Comment: @Andreas I know. But the definition of `Function1` is what reveals the "mapping" from the kotlin-syntax to the JVM-code.