# Is it possible to clone names from the list to the specific array without creating a loop?

Tags: java

I have 35 categories inside this list `List<CategoriesModel> categoriesModelList;`, and I want to clone all names and put them inside this array `String[] namesList`, I'm currently cloning names using this code but I want to ask is there any method can clone names from list to the specific array without creating a loop?

```
String[] namesList = new String[categoriesModelList.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < categoriesModelList.size(); i++)
    namesList[i] = categoriesModelList.get(i).getName();
```

**CategoriesModel.java**

```
public class CategoriesModel {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private boolean supportSubcategories;

    public CategoriesModel(int id, String name, boolean supportSubcategories) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.supportSubcategories = supportSubcategories;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean isSupportSubcategories() {
        return supportSubcategories;
    }

}
```

Comment: `categoriesModelList.stream().map(CategoriesModel::getName).toArray(String[]::new)`.

Comment: Note that any solution of this can only *hide* the loop inside some other code, but there's just fundamentally no way to achieve this without iterating over each element.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thanks for your reply, My android app is targeting `API level 21` and above but the `stream` method is added in `API level 24`. Please look at this question [Is it possible to use the Java 8 Stream API on Android API < 24?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515035/is-it-possible-to-use-the-java-8-stream-api-on-android-api-24) Is there any alternative way to replace the `stream` method?

Comment: Read the accepted answer to the question you linked to all the way through: you can now use streams with any API level, thanks to desuggaring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a stream:

```java
String[] namesList = categoriesModelList.stream()
    .map(CategoriesModel::getName)
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, My android app is targeting `API level 21` and above but the `stream` method is added in `API level 24`. Please look at this question [Is it possible to use the Java 8 Stream API on Android API < 24?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515035/is-it-possible-to-use-the-java-8-stream-api-on-android-api-24) Is there any alternative way to replace the `stream` method?

Comment: If you can't use streams, then you may be stuck with loops, which actually isn't that bad at all.

Comment: In this situation, I'll use the `stream` method for devices that targets `API level 24` and above and I'll use a loop for devices that targets `21, 22, and 23`. All answers are correct but I'll select your answer as the correct answer depending on the post date.

Answer (score 1):

anyway you have to use loop operation.
but stream is more elegant.

```java
String[] namesList = categoriesModelList.stream()
                .map(CategoriesModel::getName)
                .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, My android app is targeting `API level 21` and above but the `stream` method is added in `API level 24`. Please look at this question [Is it possible to use the Java 8 Stream API on Android API < 24?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515035/is-it-possible-to-use-the-java-8-stream-api-on-android-api-24) Is there any alternative way to replace the `stream` method?

Answer (score 1):

Use `java.util.stream` for it:

```
String[] names = categoriesModelList.stream()
     .map(category -> category.getName())
     .collect(Collectors.toList())
     .toArray(new String[]{});
```

Another variant avoid stream():

```
List<String> namesList = new LinkedList<>();
categoriesModelList.forEach(category -> namesList.add(category.getName()));
String[] names = namesList.toArray(new String[]{});
```

But this is just a workaround

Comment: Why do category -> category.getName() when it can be simplified to a double colon?

Comment: It is for better understanding for the new person at Streams and static references

Comment: @MorganS42 the difference is essentially irrelevant. On the other hand, you could have picked up on `collect(toList()).toArray(...)`, which should just be `toArray(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, My android app is targeting `API level 21` and above but the `stream` method is added in `API level 24`. Please look at this question [Is it possible to use the Java 8 Stream API on Android API < 24?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515035/is-it-possible-to-use-the-java-8-stream-api-on-android-api-24) Is there any alternative way to replace the `stream` method?

Comment: It's more resource cunsomptional, but as I said, new person at static references and lambdas can be confused

Comment: @SC291 I added a little bit uggly, but a solution without `stream()`

Comment: @tohhant Look at this method [setItems](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AlertDialog.Builder#setItems(java.lang.CharSequence[],%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener)) in android documentation, It accepts an only array as a parameter. Thank you for your time and +1 for your effort :)