# Android, Sleep without blocking the UI in one line of code please

Tags: android

This is a part of a card game I'm writing, notice the mHandler.postDelayed line, you can't really except me to write it every time I need the UI thread to sleep right? how can I make it one line of code?

```
    public void onDealClick(View view) {
    reset();
    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (mBalance - mBetAmount < 0) {
        showToast("Not enough chips! Resetting your chips to 1000");
        mBalance = 1000;
    }
    mBalance -= mBetAmount;
    mBalanceTextView.setText("Balance: " + mBalance);
    mPlayerHand.dealACard(mDeck, true);
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDealerHand.dealACard(mDeck, true);
        }
    }, 1000);
    mPlayerHand.dealACard(mDeck, true);
    mDealerHand.dealACard(mDeck, false);
    mPlayerHand.updateHandValueText();
    if (mPlayerHand.getCard(0).getValue() == mPlayerHand.getCard(1).getValue()) {
        mPlayerOptions.showButtons(
                PlayerOptions.HIT,
                PlayerOptions.STAND,
                PlayerOptions.SURRENDER,
                PlayerOptions.DOUBLE,
                PlayerOptions.SPLIT);
    } else {
        mPlayerOptions.showButtons(PlayerOptions.HIT, PlayerOptions.STAND, PlayerOptions.SURRENDER, PlayerOptions.DOUBLE);
    }
    if (mPlayerHand.getmHardValue() == 21) {
        endOfHand((int)(mBetAmount * 2.5), "BLACKJACK! You Win ", " Chips");
    }
}
```

It's this part I want to make shorter

```
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mDealerHand.dealACard(mDeck, true);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: you know that delay means the player gets two cards before the dealer gets one ... blackjack on Android: _you're doing it wrong_

Comment: Blundell I know, it was just an example of an Handler

Answer (score 0):

The literal answer:

```
dealTheDealerACardInOneSecond();
```

is a one liner, to call this method

```
private void dealTheDealerACardInOneSecond() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mDealerHand.dealACard(mDeck, true);
    }
   }, 1000);
}
```

But really it looks like your game architecture is wrong, I'm not sure what that delay is, maybe its for animation, but you need a rethink (I'm not sure what you ar etrying to achieve so can't even give you a pointer)

Comment: The delay later will be for animations, right now it's aimed for smoothness appearance of the cards, balance going up or down, what ever needs to be smooth so the player will notice what changes. isn't there a way without transferring this code to another method? I will have alot of this sleep kinds, not just for dealing cards, I want something more general...

Comment: Java 6 is pretty verbose in this respect, unless you do something like the other answer is hinting at

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambdas for Runnable

```
() -> mDealerHand.dealACard(mDeck, true);
```

This is equal to your Runnable

```
new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    mDealerHand.dealACard(mDeck, true);
  }
};
```

Comment: I'm targeting API 17

Comment: You can use Java8 in Gingerbread. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35934528/does-java-8-work-on-android-api-24-and-above-or-you-can-use-in-lower-api